# is there any function to extract several rows (not continuous) from data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to extract several rows (not one after the other) from data frame. The range of rows that should be removed is in another data frame.

I have tried to extract the rows with for loop, but unfortunately only the last range is removed.

this is the code line I used (inside of 'for' loop, while 'i' is the variable):

```
new_df <- main_df[-(erase_df$starts[i]:erase_df$stops[i]),]
```

for example:
this is the data frame that I want to change (main_df)

```
> main_df
   v1  v2     v3
1   1 bla blabla
2   2 bla blabla
3   3 bla blabla
4   4 bla blabla
5   5 bla blabla
6   6 bla blabla
7   7 bla blabla
8   8 bla blabla
9   9 bla blabla
10 10 bla blabla
11 11 bla blabla
12 12 bla blabla
13 13 bla blabla
14 14 bla blabla
15 15 bla blabla
```

this is the data frame (erase_df) that include the ranges of rows that I want to remove ('starts' vector indicate the first  range of rows should be removed and 'stops' vector indicates the last row should be removed in that range)

```
> erase_df
  starts stops
1      3     5
2      9    10
3     12    14
```

so the new data frame should look like this:

```
> new_df
   v1  v2     v3
1   1 bla blabla
2   2 bla blabla
6   6 bla blabla
7   7 bla blabla
8   8 bla blabla
11 11 bla blabla
15 15 bla blabla
```

I expected output looks like (new_df) as I mentioned above, but instead of it, only the last range from erase_df has removed (starts = 12, stops = 14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `Map` the `seq` function over `erase_df` to create a sequence of rows to remove for each row, then `unlist` them all into a single vector, you can subset `main_df` with the negative of that vector to remove the rows in the given ranges.

```
remove <- unlist(Map(seq, erase_df[[1]], erase_df[[2]]))

main_df[-remove,]
#    v1  v2     v3
# 1:  1 bla blabla
# 2:  2 bla blabla
# 3:  6 bla blabla
# 4:  7 bla blabla
# 5:  8 bla blabla
# 6: 11 bla blabla
# 7: 15 bla blabla
```

Or, for a more complex option that could be more efficient with larger data (haven't tested, just guesssing)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(main_df)
setDT(erase_df)

setkey(erase_df, starts, stops)
main_df[, v0 := v1]
for_anti <- 
  foverlaps(main_df, erase_df, by.x = c('v0', 'v1'), type = 'within',
            nomatch = NULL)

main_df[!for_anti, on = .(v1)]
#    v1  v2     v3 v0
# 1:  1 bla blabla  1
# 2:  2 bla blabla  2
# 3:  6 bla blabla  6
# 4:  7 bla blabla  7
# 5:  8 bla blabla  8
# 6: 11 bla blabla 11
# 7: 15 bla blabla 15
```